# C# Runtime Error

Tags: c#, runtime

I have been trying to solve the following problem in the following link:

https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1010

And this is my code:

```
using System;

namespace URIProblemsBeginner {

 class Program

 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int PRODUCT_ONE_CODE, PRODUCT_TWO_CODE, PRODUCT_ONE_UNITS, PRODUCT_TWO_UNITS;
        float PRODUCT_ONE_PRICE, PRODUCT_TWO_PRICE, VALUE_TO_PAY;

        PRODUCT_ONE_CODE = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        PRODUCT_ONE_UNITS = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        PRODUCT_ONE_PRICE = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
        PRODUCT_TWO_CODE = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        PRODUCT_TWO_UNITS = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        PRODUCT_TWO_PRICE = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

        VALUE_TO_PAY = (PRODUCT_ONE_UNITS * PRODUCT_ONE_PRICE) + (PRODUCT_TWO_UNITS * PRODUCT_TWO_PRICE);

        Console.WriteLine("VALOR A PAGAR: R$ " + VALUE_TO_PAY.ToString("F2"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Whenever I am running this code for testing it in Visual Studio 2015, it runs without any error. But whenever I am submitting this to the URI Compiler, it is not accepting my answer and is giving a run time error.
I am not sure if there is a bug or not?

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Log you exception by doing a build in debug mode and catching the exception in try catch. If you are using valid input possibility is of not using right target, like any cpu , 32 bit , 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the problem statement...

> The input file contains two lines of data. In each line there will be
>   3 values: two integers and a floating value with 2 digits after the
>   decimal point.

... but your application as written would be looking for six lines of data.  One line for product one code, one line for product one price, etc.

I believe the approach you want is to read a line and split it into its three components.  Something along the lines of the following.

using System;

```
namespace URIProblemsBeginner
{
    internal class Program
    {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int PRODUCT_ONE_CODE, PRODUCT_TWO_CODE, PRODUCT_ONE_UNITS, PRODUCT_TWO_UNITS;
        float PRODUCT_ONE_PRICE, PRODUCT_TWO_PRICE, VALUE_TO_PAY;

        ConvertInput(Console.ReadLine(), out PRODUCT_ONE_CODE, out PRODUCT_ONE_UNITS, out PRODUCT_ONE_PRICE);
        ConvertInput(Console.ReadLine(), out PRODUCT_TWO_CODE, out PRODUCT_TWO_UNITS, out PRODUCT_TWO_PRICE);

        VALUE_TO_PAY = (PRODUCT_ONE_UNITS*PRODUCT_ONE_PRICE) + (PRODUCT_TWO_UNITS*PRODUCT_TWO_PRICE);

        Console.WriteLine("VALOR A PAGAR: R$ " + VALUE_TO_PAY.ToString("F2"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ConvertInput(string input, out int CODE, out int UNITS, out float PRICE)
    {
        string[] split = input.Split(' ');
        CODE = Convert.ToInt32(split[0]);
        UNITS = Convert.ToInt32(split[1]);
        PRICE = Convert.ToSingle(split[2]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, but you did not specify exactly what you are entering when you run it in VS.  If you are entering your data on six separate lines and the URI compiler is providing data on only 2 lines then of course you will see a different result.  Look at the input samples... did you type "12 1 5.30" all on one line as shown?

Comment: The OP is asking why he might get a runtime error on the site but not in VS.  If the URI process is supplying 2 lines of input data and he has 6 Console.ReadLine commands in his code that seems like something that might cause a runtime error.  If I'm wrong, I'm wrong, but given the information provided I still think it is a reasonable hypothesis.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Program
{

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int PRODUCT_ONE_CODE, PRODUCT_TWO_CODE, PRODUCT_ONE_UNITS, PRODUCT_TWO_UNITS;
        float PRODUCT_ONE_PRICE, PRODUCT_TWO_PRICE, VALUE_TO_PAY;

        ConvertInput(Console.ReadLine(), out PRODUCT_ONE_CODE, out PRODUCT_ONE_UNITS, out PRODUCT_ONE_PRICE);
        ConvertInput(Console.ReadLine(), out PRODUCT_TWO_CODE, out PRODUCT_TWO_UNITS, out PRODUCT_TWO_PRICE);

        VALUE_TO_PAY = (PRODUCT_ONE_UNITS + PRODUCT_ONE_PRICE) + (PRODUCT_TWO_UNITS + PRODUCT_TWO_PRICE);

        Console.WriteLine("VALOR A PAGAR: R$ " + VALUE_TO_PAY.ToString("F2"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static void ConvertInput(string input, out int CODE , out int UNITS, out float PRICE)
    {
        List<string> split = input.Split(' ').ToList();
        string[] changedInput =new string[3];
        for (int i = 3 - split.Count; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            split.Add("0");
            if (split.Count ==3 )
            {
                break;
            }

        }
        int.TryParse(split[0], out CODE);
        int.TryParse(split[1], out UNITS);
        float.TryParse(split[2], out PRICE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add comments with explanations.

Comment: For a useful answer explain why this is an answer to the question.